# package convention for main() method`s Java class

Tags: java, naming-conventions, package

I am building an standalone Java application.

In that, i have to use the class with `main()` method. As this is the class where all execution begins, i usually place in one of package structure

```
com.<company-name>.<project-name>.init
com.<company-name>.<project-name>.main
com.<company-name>.<project-name>.server
com.<company-name>.<project-name>.initializer
```

My Question is,

- are above package name for given purpose making sense ? if not then any suggestions?
- is there standard for naming this ?

Comment: Looks perfectly fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I create a project with a main class I usually put it in the topmost package of the application 'com.acmeglobal.killerapplication' and give it a simple name like 'App', 'Main' or 'Start'.

I try to keep my main class as small as possible; it only bootstraps the application. If parsing of application arguments is even slightly nontrivial I even create a separate class for that.

Of your suggested package names I prefer 'main', after that either 'init' or 'initialization' although I think initialization should not be the concern of the main class. The package called 'server' seems misleading to me because it suggests that there is also a client, which I don't think you intended.

Answer (score 2):

> are above package name for given purpose making sense ? if not then
>   any suggestions?

I think it make sense. Merging main and init is also fine for me if your main only contains the Main class.

> is there standard for naming this ?

No.

Answer (score 1):

The packages you suggest look fine, but just to be thorough they should be prefixed with the domain name in reverse.  So if the company `Acme` has domain `www.acmeglobal.com` their package structure would be prefixed with `com.acmeglobal` instead of `com.acme`.

Adhering to this standard reduces the likelihood of developers creating colliding classes.

Answer (score 0):

Defining package structure is for your own use. If you place your code in proper package structure then it will help in future for maintenance and increase the readability.